# Validating selected values against particular column of the table

Tags: jquery

Please find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/z55vY/)

What is the issue ?

When user picks the city from the drowdown , code will validated selected city name against all td (all coulmn).  But I want to validate selected city name against column' city' only.

```
 $("#search").change(function () {
 var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

 $("table tr").each(function (index) {
    if (!index) return;
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
        var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
        $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
        return not_found;
    });
 });
 });
```

Comment: You can use `:eq(3)` to fetch 4th column like `$(this).find("td:eq(3)")`

Comment: Thanks  Satpal.  Can you post your comment as answer so that I can accept the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**:eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) Selector to fetch 4th column like

> Select the element at index n within the matched set

*Code Example*, Use

```
$(this).find("td:eq(3)")
```

instead of

```
$(this).find("td")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z55vY/2/)

Note: its zero-based index of the element to match.